# amass enaum -list command issue

Tags: security, scanning

amass enaum -list command provides no output. Is there any config file to setup for this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk0jS.png)

I tried this command:-
amass enaum -list
and I was expecting the output like this in below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCopK.png)